# How do you make a looping connection in Omnetpp

Tags: connection, omnet++

I have three people in the simulation, bob, bobby and boba. I can make them cyclic like
bob-bobby-boba-bob-bobby->>>> but i don't knnow how to make one that bounce., bob-bobby-boba-bobby-bob.

I tried

```
connections:
        a.outG --> b.inG;
        b.outG --> c.inG;
        c.outG --> b.inG;
        b.outG --> a.inG;
```

but it says that the connection is already blocked??

Answer (score 1):

Define every gate as a vector gate, i.e.

```
gates:
  input  inG[];
  output outG[];
```

Then in your connections use "++" to mark that next gate of vector is created:

```
connections:
    a.outG++ --> b.inG++;
    b.outG++ --> c.inG++;
    c.outG++ --> b.inG++;
    b.outG++ --> a.inG++;
```